# Open Password Protected Workbook with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have wb1 and wb2. wb1 is used for data entry and wb2 is used to record that data. wb2 is password protected (let's say with "password").

The VBA below is in wb1 and is run on a button click. As it is now, a box pops up requesting the password for wb2 before the VBA is done running. Is there a way to use VBA to enter "password" in that box?

I'm fairly new to VBA, so I'm open to other suggestions as well. Thanks!

```
Sub OpenClose()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users...")  'I have taken out the rest of the file path

wb1.Activate
    Sheets("Entry").Activate
        Range("A1:A5").Select
            Selection.Copy

wb2.Activate
    Sheets("Log").Activate
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

wb2.Save
wb2.Close

Set wb1 = Nothing
Set wb2 = Nothing

MsgBox "Logged and saved."

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at the `WorkBook.Unprotect` method. Here's the MSDN for it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196695.aspx

Comment: FWIW - you can simply write `wb1.Sheets("Entry").Range("A1:A5").Copy wb2.Sheets("Log").Range("A1")`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When opening `wb2` pass your "password" argument as the `Password` parameter:

```
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users...", Password:="password")
```

See [Workbooks.Open Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This works for a file that requires a password to open it. When opening `wb2` pass your "password" argument as the `Password` parameter:

`Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users...", Password:="password")`

If the file is set to open in Read Only but requires a password to Modify it use this:

`Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users...", writeresPassword:="password")`

Answer (score -3):

Checkout this code might be resolved your issue for which you looking for

```
ThisWorkbook.Password = "1"
ThisWorkbook.Save
ThisWorkbook.Close
```