# Copy and paste range from multiple closed workbooks; Excel can't access data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy Range(A14:L26) from all closed workbooks in a file on my desktop. The data should be pasted in a master workbook, which is my current workbook.

Also only the values and not the formula or formatting should be pasted. So basically only what is visible in the cells should be pasted.

The values should be pasted in a table in order for them to be visualized later.

When running the code I get the notification that Excel can't access the files in the folder on my desktop as they might be protected.

How can I "unprotect" them via VBA so I can copy the data.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySpecialPaste()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim y As Workbook

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
.Title = "Choose Target Folder Path"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xlsm*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\XXX")
Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Important Information")

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'Copy data on "Important Information" sheet to "Evaluation" Sheet in 
 other workbook

With wb.Sheets("Important Information")
   If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb.Sheets("Important _ 
    Information").Range("A14:L26")) <> 0 Then
   lRow = .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'not sure which Range to 
                                                 'add here
   wb.Sheets("Important Information").Range("A14:L26" & lRow).Copy
   ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial 
   Paste:=xlPasteValues
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Else
   End If
End With


wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
'Get next file name
myFile = Dir
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "I hope that worked!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649347/unprotect-sheet-workbook-excel-vba - To unprotect sheet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074526/open-password-protected-workbook-with-vba - To open password protected excel workbook

Comment: @SolarMike I'm guessing you mean integrating the opening and closing in the code? Can you point me in the direction of how to do so?

Comment: @newguy thank you! Do you know how to unprotect all of the sheets in the file on my desktop instead of having to add the name of every single one of them in my code?

Comment: Yes, use `For each wK in Thisworkbook.Worksheets: wk.Unprotect("password"): Next`

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately still can't access the files

Comment: Step through the code and find which line errors

Comment: Set y = Application.Workbooks.Open("Users:\XXX")

Comment: Is where there is a bug

Comment: it still tells me that the data can't be accessed since it possible is protected. I did not protect the data and the files have been created by me so I don't understand why it does that.

Comment: The check the path and check if the workbook is protected by the password. If yes then you need to open it by the method explained in one of the links above.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074526/open-password-protected-workbook-with-vba Try this

Comment: @newguy the workbooks are not protected by password that's why I don't understand why Excel can't access them